# C# implicit cast from base class to extended (System.Reflection.Assembly)

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, upcasting

I've been working the project mentioned [c-sharp-compilerresults-generateinmemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871955/c-sharp-compilerresults-generateinmemory/24872256#24872256).

I've been writing a lot of code to get my "class discovery" implemented. It works cool, but I realized it would be a lot more efficient if I implemented everything as an derived class of `System.Reflection.Assembly'.

So with that new derived class written I hit a problem. When I try to assign the base class to the new derived class it throws an error, just the normal `did you miss an explicit cast` error.

**I thought C# did implicit casting for extended types?**

So I have some source code like this...

```
Assembly asm = MyCompilerResults.CompiledAssembly(); /* this works */
Interface asmInterface = new Interface();
asmInterface = asm; /* bad */
asmInterface = (Interface)asm; /* bad */


public class Interface : Assembly {
    public Interface() {} // I always just declare the empty constructor.

    public void Helpermethod1() {}
    public void Helpermethod2() {}
    public void Helpermethod3() {}
};
```

So as it's only the second week I've been writing C# I have to ask...
**How do I add the base class to my class?**

The question here...    [Why can't I write an implicit operator from a Base class to a Derived class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853141/why-cant-i-write-an-implicit-operator-from-a-base-class-to-a-derived-class-in-c)
This seems to indicate my casting should work unless I'm misunderstanding the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missunderstood something. What you are trying to achieve is to assign base class to derived one. It's not possible on almost every case.

Consider following:

```
public class A 
{
}

public class B : A
{
}

A a = new B();

// some code

B b = (B)a; // it is possible. Behind the scenes, variable a is of B type.
```

but:

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B)a; //IT'S NOT ALLOWED. The variable a is of type A that has 
            // no "knowledge" about B class.
```

In your case, `CompiledAssembly()` returns `Assembly` instance that has no any information about `Interface` class, so it cannot be directly casted.

There are two options. Write wrapper:

```
public class Interface 
{
     private readonly Assembly underlyingAssembly;
     publiic Interface(Assembly asm)
     {
        this.underlyingAssembly = asm;
     }

     // other methods
}

Assembly someAsm = MyCompilerResults.CompiledAssembly();
Interface interface = new Interface(someAsm);
```

or write extension methods:

```
public static class AsmExt
{
     public static void SomeMethod(this Assembly asm)
     {
     }
}

Assembly someAsm = MyCompilerResults.CompiledAssembly();
someAsm.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Awesome, extension methods are totally the functionality I'm looking for. Also thanks for clearing up my misnomer on how C# classes cast.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to acchieve something different here, which can be done by using [extensionmethods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension)

You have to create a static class which then offers the functionality to extend the object like this:

```
public static class AssemblyExtension
{

    public static void HelperMethod1(this Assembly asm)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(asm.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
Assembly asm = MyCompilerResults.CompiledAssembly(); 
asm.HelperMethod1();
```